# Session State Anti-Pattern (or Global State in general)

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, session, design-patterns

I know the SOLID principles and other design patterns fairly well and have been programming for some time now - seeing many a bit of code throughout the years. Having said that, I'm having trouble coming up with a name to give the pattern, or lack thereof, to bits of code I've been dealing with at a current engagement.

The application is an ASP.NET C# WebForms application, backed by a SQL Server/Mainframe backend (more mainframe than backend) and it's riddled with Session State properties being accessed/mutated from multiple pages/classes.

Accessing/mutating global variables/application state was usually shunned upon while I was in school. Apparently the creators of this magnificent application didn't think it was such a bad idea.

**Question:**

Is there a name for such a pattern/anti-pattern that relies so heavily on Session State? I'd like to call the pig by its name ...

Comment: I think you're referring to [Global State](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/148108). BTW, you're lucky they told you about this in school.

Comment: Considering HTTP's inherent lack of state, maybe non-RESTful development.

Comment: I would have assumed it would just be the "global variable" ant-pattern. Can't find any reference to global variables being directly called an anti-pattern though, just anti-patterns (eg singleton) who's root cause is global mutable state.

Comment: "Accessing/mutating global variables/application state was usually shunned upon while I was in school. Apparently the creators of this magnificent application didn't think it was such a bad idea." Welcome to the real world. 95% of all code is terrible. That doesn't mean you have to leave it as bad as you found it though :)

Comment: @Earlz been in that world for a while now. just wanted to give it a better name than "spaghetti code" ... "big ball of mud" sounds good and get the point accross in a PC manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Big ball of mud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud)?
[Action at a distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance_%28computer_science%29)?
[Spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)?

Comment: "big ball of mud" is nice and work-safe, better than the "pile of shit" term I'd be tempted to use...

Answer (score 0):

[Peanut butter](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/the-peanut-butter-theory-of-user-interface-design.html).   It is refer to the UI design, but I think it is also applied to software design: It just won't work to build a complete system and then, in the final stages of development, spread the code over it like peanut butter